# How to display as selected, the model relation records for select input options in nested foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, loops, select, foreach

The project is not mine and it needs to be a convertion from laravel-backpack to default laravel views, controllers, etc
The link shows the backpack view but imagine i want the same views and functionalities
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Y_KmyTv2i46fekr-25dO6qT8WTnq3H8sRGjMX2O0pA3louH5qfA_uNHlESm8Vci_EQ7ThCJzFl0NT-yU4xb-BZzFiP3WoWilZm1rV6Z994aYiE2e1n08XvE5tznipb3C9CGcVar-gVi9d9ewzx9L52mOaOTm_a5D01ThRIZk6CbIuHao_Mn7mzETHc1dGA

The problem is i cannot show the product attributes inside each taxonomy model as selected, meaning it needs to show the related attributes of a product, inside each taxonomy
I have product attribute and taxonomy models.
The page i want to display them is the edit product page inside two foreach loops, first loop maps each taxonomy model records as header for the attributes that are related to each current prduct page, and inside each taxonomy is the attribute models that connect with each of the taxonomy only showen as header. Inside each taxonomy->attribute option i need to display as selected the current product attributes for each one of the taxonomy loop. I hope iam understood by each reader and thank you in advance.

BELLOW IS THE CODE..........

Product.php model relation with attribute is manytomany

```
public function attributes(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class);
    }
```

Attribute model relations with taxonomy is one taxonomy to many attributes

```
public function taxonomy(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Taxonomy::class, 'taxonomy_id', 'id','taxonomies');
    }

    public function products(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class );
    }
```

Taxonomy model relations has attribute model with onetomany relation type

```
public function attributes(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class, 'taxonomy_id','id');
    }
```

### I also have a pivot for AttributeProduct

blade view inside the product edit page

```
@foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy)
                        <div class="controls">
                            <a type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="remoteAttributeProduct({{$taxonomy->id}})" title="Remove line">X</a>
                        </div>
                        <label class="form-label">Taxonomy</label>
                        <input style="color:#000000" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ '$taxonomy->name' }}" value="{{ $taxonomy->name }}" readonly>

                        <label class="form-label {{ $errors->has('attribute') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">Attributes for {{ $taxonomy->name }}</label>
                        <select style="width:100%" class="productattributeselect form-group js-example-basic-multiple"
                                name="taxonomyId-[{{$taxonomy->id}}]"
                                multiple="multiple">

                                @foreach($taxonomy->attributes as $attribute)
                                    <option class="productattributeoption" name="attributes" value="{{$attribute->id}}" {{$product->attributes==$loop->index?'selected':''}}>
                                        {{$attribute->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                        </select>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: A little confused. Is the taxonomy an input field or select? In the screenshot it looks like a `select` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using {{ in_array($attribute->id, $product->attributes->pluck('id')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : ''}}